# Missing token and extraneous input

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I use Python3.g4 grammar from [here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/python3/Python3.g4) and try to modify it. I want to add type hints, starting with 3 chars "#t ". They can be on separate line and after statements.
Added and modified rules:

```
simple_stmt
 : small_stmt ( ';' small_stmt )* ';'? type_comment? NEWLINE
 | type_comment NEWLINE
 ;

type_comment
 : TYPE_COMMENT
 ;

TYPE_COMMENT
 : '#' 't' ' ' ~[\r\n]*
 ;
```

Other relevant rules:

```
stmt
 : simple_stmt 
 | compound_stmt
 ;

fragment COMMENT
 : '#' ~[\r\n]*
 ;

compound_stmt
 : if_stmt 
 | while_stmt 
 | for_stmt 
 | try_stmt 
 | with_stmt 
 | funcdef 
 | classdef 
 | decorated
 ;

while_stmt
 : WHILE test ':' suite ( ELSE ':' suite )?
 ;

suite
 : simple_stmt 
 | NEWLINE INDENT stmt+ DEDENT
 ;
```

With input

```
a = 1 #t int

#t int

#t str
s = "string"
```

I get following errors:

```
line 3:0 missing NEWLINE at '#t int'
line 5:0 extraneous input '#t str' expecting NEWLINE
```

When line

```
| type_comment NEWLINE
```

changed to

```
| type_comment
```

I receive other similar errors. What is the correct version of this grammar?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the `#t ...` gets matched by a rule defined before your `TYPE_COMMENT`. Try to define `TYPE_COMMENT` as the first lexer rule. If that doesn't help, please post your entire grammar.

Comment: There are definitely some bugs in your grammar (see my issue in Git), and Antlr4 docs are half-closed, so I switch to other tool.To constuct more robust grammars please test them by code generation or in some other way. I'm tired to struggle with all-Antlr4-things and give up.

Comment: You sound like you're entitled to quick and free help. The issue you created only 19 hours ago. And I never claimed the grammar I wrote is free of bugs.  You're welcome trying to help you. Good riddance to you, go right ahead and give up: no skin off my back.